# Fitting a photo into a frame with CSS

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position, css-transforms

I have fitted an image into a frame with CSS for a certain size but want this be fully responsive. In a CSS3 world of Flexbox and loads of options with transforms. How can i ensure this image stays within the rotated frame at all sizes, perhaps using some newer CSS properties?

```css
.main {
  position:relative;
}

.insert {
  /* max-height: 300px; */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 19%;
    height: 110px;
    width: 110px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    transform: rotate(20deg);
    left: 13.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<img class="holder" style="max-height:300px" src="https://s15.postimg.cc/5fpragxnv/holder.jpg">

<img class="insert" style="max-height:300px" src="https://s15.postimg.cc/h4tqygyx7/insert.jpg">
</div>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8zk0j5p/)

Comment: Why not using fix values for the position?

Comment: use fixed position in media queries.

Comment: Yes, a fixed position on the main div is also an option https://jsfiddle.net/1okjy4xw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

instead of left in % use left in vh for .insert

```
.main {
    position:relative;
}

.insert {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 19%;
    height: 110px;
    width: 110px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    transform: rotate(20deg);
    left: 26vh;
}
```

Comment: For me it's 22vh that fits in the frame

Comment: @Gracie, might be..i tested on fiddle, if your problem is solved, please mark it as accepted